# SQL to list data from 2 tables joined by a foreign key

Tags: sql, list, foreign-keys

Sorry for the very simple question, I have tried researching, but the examples are with too specific to a particular person's issue or, sites only explain foreign key constraints for Creating,altering or dropping in a table.

Anyway, I have 2 tables, 1 containing 2 columns being the Unique primary key and the other post codes:

```
PCID   postCode
1      CB1 4PY
2      CB2 9GH
3      CB23 4DG
```

and the second is people, 4 columns, first PK, second FK from PostCodes, then forename and surename.

```
PId     PCID    firstName   lastName
1       1       Fred        Bloggs
2       2       Arthur      Brown
3       1       Mary        Bloggs
4       4       Nigel       Wilson
```

I just want to be able to list postcodes and the names of people who live there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT n.firstName, n.lastName FROM Names n JOIN PostCode USING(PCID)
```

`Name` and `PostCode` here is the table names, change to yours.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Thanks, that nice artice! I have updated my answer.

Comment: Cool i had no idea this USING could be used to join. sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT t2.FirstName,t2.LastName , t1.PostCode
FROM postcodetablename t1
JOIN namestablename t2 on t1.PcId=t2.PcId
```